# Keeping models between spring boot and angular application in sync. Alternatives?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, dto

In client-server applications with spring-boot and angular. Most resources I find explain how to expose REST endpoint from spring boot and consume it from angular with an http client.

Most of the time, communicating in JSON is preconized, maintaining DTOs (DataTransfertObject) in both angular and spring boot side.

I wonder if people with fullstack experience knows some alternative avoiding maintaining DTOs in both front and backend, maybe sharing models between the two ends of the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Swagger](https://swagger.io/) would be a good tool to use here.

You can take a code-first approach which will generate a swagger spec from your Java controllers & TOs or a spec-first approach which will generate your Java controllers & TOs from a swagger spec.

Either way, you can then use the swagger spec to generate a set of TypeScript interfaces for the client side.

Answer (score 1):

As Pace said [Swagger](https://swagger.io/specification/) would be a great feature that you can use. In this case plus having great [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAPI_Specification) for the API endpoints you can sync object models between frontend and backend. You have to just use the `.json` or `.yaml` file of Swagger to generate the services and object models on the frontend side by using [ng-swagger-gen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-swagger-gen).
Then put the command for generating services and object model in `package.json` when you wanna build or run your application for instance:

```
...
    "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "ng-swagger-gen && ng serve",
    "build": "ng-swagger-gen && ng build -prod"
     ...
  },
...
```

So after running one of these commands you will have updated object models and if an object property name or type changed, add/remove object property you will get the error and you have to fix it first then move forward.

Note: Just keep in mind the services and object models will be generated based on the Swagger file so it always should be updated.

PS: I was working on a project that we even every code on the backend side was generated based on the Swagger file ;) so they just change the Swagger file and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult topic, since we are dealing with two different technology stacks. The only way I see is to generate those objects from a common data model.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good, doesn't work. It is not just about maintaining dto's.
Lets say api changes String to List. It is not enough to update your typescript dto from string to string[]. There is logic behind string manipulation that now needs to handle list of strings. Personally i do not find that troublesome to maintain dto's on both sides. Small tradeoff for flexibility and cleaner code (you will have different methods in different dto's)